# in app purchase limit

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

we are talking about some new apps and have an idea. 
the problem is, we want to purchase some items in app, about 150. is this possible or does apple restrict inapppurchases to a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a SKU limit of 3000-3500 items, according to this blog posts.

http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/3345687143/why-are-vendors-annoyed-by-this-iap-thing
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/in-app-purchase/selling-content-on-the-app-store

Update: in the iTC User Guide the limit is defined with 3000 SCU items.

Comment: Update: Apparently it's 10.000 now. (as of Feb 2012)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no restriction regarding this. You can purchase as many items as you want.